# media query-website view on smartphone

Tags: css, media-queries

I have tried both `min-width , max-width`  and `min-device-width , max-device-width` ,but none of them worked on smartphone(tested on iPhone) as expected.Smartphone view remain same when either one is used.I just get the same view as laptop(My laptop 1224px) on my phone but with smaller size.Images would clarify my point.

This is what I get on laptop(browser maximized),when `min-width(1224px)` is used

**View 1**

[image]

When I use `min-width(320px) and max-width(480px)` and shrink the browser on laptop,I get this

**View 2**

[image]

which is my expected result on smartphone.But I don't get this view on smartphone,even after using `min-device-width(320px) and max-device-width(480px)`.Both `width` and `device-width` gives me `view 1` with smaller view on iPhone(smaller images and tiny font)

How to get rid of this problem.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show more of your CSS.

Comment: my css contains couple hundred lines.Anyway,I'm getting the view on browser when browser size is 320px.So,why not on phone?

Comment: Do you have a `viewport`  meta tag in your html `head`? such as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: No I don't have that.I have no idea about that.Is it causing the trouble?

Comment: I added an answer that should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you said you do not have a `viewport` meta tag in your `head`, you will not have consistent scaling in mobile devices. In the `<head>` of your html, add the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Source: [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)